# Storing username in sesson data with asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, asp.net-membership

On my asp.net website I have membership functions enabled which require users to login.
I would like to store the username in the session data for a query which will be used once they have logged in.

On my login page I have the following code to store the session data but it does not work:

```
Session["UserName"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
```

The query will not load any results because the control parameter (session[username]) returns empty.

Can anyone suggest what could be the reason why its not working?

Comment: Check if username is present in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name. If forms authentication is used, it should have the logged in user name.

Comment: often the user info isn't available until the **next** page load. You may have to redirect to a "hop" page after login and redirect back to the page the user requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

often the user info isn't available until the next page load.

You may have to redirect to a "hop" page after login and redirect back to the page the user requested.

Here's how to do it with MVC

Login:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Hop(returnUrl);
    }
}
```

Hop page: It's at this point that the user info is actually available.

```
public ActionResult Hop(string returnUrl)
{
    Session["UserName"] = User.Identity.Name;
    return Redirect(returnUrl);
}
```

Comment: You are correct, the session isnt stored because it isnt yet available. I havent used your solution but the information is correct. What I simply did is move the line into the landing page for the login page.

Comment: glad to help. most of the time I don't end up with one "landing page" so I often have to do the hop method above

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the membership providers you should use their classes to grab user information.  Try using

```
Session["UserName"] = Membership.GetUser().UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Login control on the page? If so, you can get the username directly from the control, like so:
(assuming the Login control is named loginControl)

```
Session["UserName"] = loginControl.UserName;
```